# Bootstrapping for missing data in a linear mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, bootstrap

I am trying to analyse data from an experiment. I would like to use a linear mixed model with either lme() from the package nlme or lmer() from lme4 in R.

In my experiment subjects were randomly assigned to one of two treatments (between subjects factor trt) and then the subjects completed multiple tasks which were a combination of two factors (within subjects factors X and Y). So we have multiple measures of each combination of X and y. 
Also, some of the subjects completed more tasks than others.

My data looks like this:

```
dat()

trt     subject X   Y   outcome
A       1       o   m   11.5
A       1       o   d    7.3
A       1       l   m   11.2
A       1       l   d   11.3
A       1       o   m   12.3
A       1       o   d    6.2
A       1       l   m    2.4
A       2       o   m   13.4
A       2       o   d    9.4
... ...     ...     ... ... ...
B       45      o   x    3.9
B       45      o   y    6.7
B       45      l   x    3.4
B       45      l   y   12.5
B       45      o   x   16.3
B       46      o   x    8.9
... ...     ...     ... ... ...
```

So there is a different number of observation for each subject.

I thought that this would be the right formula after excluding missing values (so that each subject has the same number of observations):

```
model<- lme(outcome~ trt*x*y, random= ~1 | subject/x/y, data= dat, method= "ML")
```

also, because the tasks are part of a bigger quantity of tasks I thought about an extra variable "task" and include it like that:

```
model<- lme(outcome~ trt*x*y, random= ~1 | subject/tasks/x/y, data= dat, method= "ML")
```

But with this approach much of my data goes missing. I have read about bootstrapping for missing values. Is bootstrapping suitable here?

I would be very, very grateful if someone helped me out because I am really confused here. Thanks a lot in advance!